# Conditionally set flags based on dates and a character variable

Tags: sas

suppose to have the following:

> ```
>  ID         Start        End       Place
> 0001      13JAN2015   20JAN2015    HospA
> 0001      21JAN2015   31DEC2015    HospA
> 0001      01JAN2018   31DEC2018    HospB
> 0001      01JAN2019   31DEC2019    HospA
> 0002      01JAN2015   31DEC2015    HospA
> 0002      01JAN2019   31OCT2019    HospA
> 0002      01NOV2019   31DEC2020    HospA
> ```
>
> .....      ........    .........    .....

I would like to set a flag for the start and a flag for the end as follows:

1. for each ID, for consecutive periods and same Place, put "1" in StartFlag column relative to the first date in Start column (first two rows of desired output); fill the remaining StartFlag and EndFlag with 0;
2. there is a jump of years for the same ID and the Place changes put "1" in StartFlag column referred to Start and 0 to the remaining (EndFlag column). This refers to rows 3 and 4 of desired output. The idea is to record the change in the Place;
3. if there are jumps of years but the Place does not change, then put: "1" in the column StarFlag for the first date in Start column, "9" to the EndFlag before the jump and "9" in the column StartFlag relative to the starting of the next non-consecutive period.

I tried with if statement. I don't know how to "call" the first date of each consecutive/non-consecutive period of each Place.

Thank you in advance

Desired output:

> ```
>  ID         Start        End       Place      StartFlag      EndFlag
> 0001      13JAN2015   20JAN2015    HospA          1             0
> 0001      21JAN2015   31DEC2015    HospA          0             0
> 0001      01JAN2018   31DEC2018    HospB          1             0
> 0001      01JAN2019   31DEC2019    HospA          1             0
> 0002      01JAN2015   30SEP2015    HospA          1             0
> 0002      01OCT2015   31DEC2015    HospA          0             9
> 0002      01JAN2019   31OCT2019    HospA          9             0            
> 0002      01NOV2019   31DEC2020    HospA          0             0
> ```
>
> .....      ........    .........    .....

Answer (score 1):

You can use BY group processing to detect the first or last observation for an ID.  And you can extend it to include PLACE by using the NOTSORTED option.  But to compare the dates you need to look back and look ahead.  Looking back is easy with the LAG() function.  Looking ahead takes a little work, here is a simple method using dataset options to read starting from the second observation.

First make sure the data is sorted by ID and START date.

```
data have;
  input ID $ (Start End) (:date.) Place $;
  format start end date9.;
cards;
0001 13JAN2015 20JAN2015 HospA
0001 21JAN2015 31DEC2015 HospA
0001 01JAN2018 31DEC2018 HospB
0001 01JAN2019 31DEC2019 HospA
0002 01JAN2015 31DEC2015 HospA
0002 01JAN2019 31OCT2019 HospA
0002 01NOV2019 31DEC2020 HospA
;

proc sort data=have;
  by id start ;
run;
```

If you tell the data step the data is grouped by ID and PLACE you can use the FIRST.PLACE and LAST.PLACE flags.  You just need to add some logic to test the date intervals.

```
data want;
  set have ;
  by id place notsorted;
  lag_end=lag(end);
  format lag_end date9.;
  set have(firstobs=2 keep=start rename=(start=next_start)) 
      have(obs=1 drop=_all_)
  ;
  if first.place then startflag = 1;
  else if lag_end+1 < start then startflag=1;
  else startflag=0;

  if last.place then endflag=1;
  else if (end+1 < next_start) then endflag=1;
  else endflag=0;

run;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for explanations and help! Unfortunately it does not take into account the change in the Place, the reason why I decided to use 9 as a code.

Comment: Huh? It definitely does take into account the change in place. That is why 4th observation is a new group because it is a different place.

Comment: Yes of course but I cannot distinguish 0001 from 0002 considering the Place. This is the reason why I used the code 9.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  What do you mean 0001 and 0002? Are you talking about the ID values?  If FIRST.ID is TRUE then by definition FIRST.PLASE is also true since the first observation for particular value of ID **must** be the first observation for whatever value of PLACE there is under that value of ID.

Answer (score 0):

The lag function is quite powerful, but here it is sufficient to use the retain statement to get the results. Normally, you have access to one row at a time in SAS due to the data vector, but by using retain you can keep values to the next row.
At first, we generate the sample data and sort it by id and start:

```
data have;
  input ID $ (Start End) (:date.) Place $;
  format start end date9.;
cards;
0001 13JAN2015 20JAN2015 HospA
0001 21JAN2015 31DEC2015 HospA
0001 01JAN2018 31DEC2018 HospB
0001 01JAN2019 31DEC2019 HospA
0002 01JAN2015 30SEP2015 HospA
0002 01OCT2015 31DEC2015 HospA
0002 01JAN2019 31OCT2019 HospA
0002 01NOV2019 31DEC2020 HospA
run;

proc sort data=have;
  by id start ;
run;
```

Now we use the retain statement to keep the values of id, start, end and place of the previous row.
(Actually, we don't need the by statement here, because first and last statements are not used.)
In this way, we can put the right values into start_flag:

```
data want (drop=prev:);
set have;
by id start;
format prev_start prev_end date9.;
retain prev_id prev_start prev_end prev_place;
if    prev_id eq id AND prev_place eq place 
  AND prev_end+1 eq start 
      then start_flag=0; 
      else start_flag=1;
if    prev_id eq id AND prev_place eq place 
  AND prev_end+1 ne start 
      then start_flag=9; 
output;
prev_id=id; prev_start=start; prev_end=end; prev_place=place;
run;
```

End_flag is a little more tricky, because we need the next row, not the previous one.
Hence, we sort our data in the reverse order and use another retain (if the data amount is huge, consider using an index or two...).

```
proc sort data=want; 
    by descending id descending start;
quit;

data want_final (drop=next_startflag);
set want;
by descending id descending start;
retain next_startflag;
if next_startflag eq 9 then end_flag=9;
                       else end_flag=0;
output;
next_startflag=start_flag;
run;
```

Finally we sort the data back in the original order:

```
proc sort data=want_final;
by id start;
quit;
```